# Does COM CoCreateInstance trace-tool exist?

Tags: com

Over the year I have had a lot time when creating an instance of a COM-class fails.
And it's always a hassle to understand why it failed, this time.

I started thinking about writing a tool, which basically does all the steps CoCreateInstance does, but with logging. (Lookup GUID in registry, find DLL to load, load DLL, find the ComFactory in the DLL etc).

This seems like a common issue, perhaps such a tool already exists?

Comment: Yeah, SysInternals' ProcMon tool works fairly well.

Comment: Well, yes. Looking at registry and file-access give you some hints on what is happening inside the black-box. 
However, here I was looking more into making the box transparent.

Comment: You can't track "finding the factory in the DLL" unless you attach as a debugger.